# Robotium & system dialogs

Tags: android, robotium

When I try to pair with Bluetooth device, system confirmation dialog with PIN appears. There are buttons "Cancel" and "OK". But I can't click them with Robotium. How can I work with Android OS dialogs in Robotium?
Thanks.

Comment: System dialogs are not part of App's window or view hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(android.R.id.button1));
```

where the 'Positive' button is android.R.id.button1, the 'Negative' button is android.R.id.button2 and 'Neutral' is android.R.id.button3.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to write a test case that spans over 2 applications.
But, if it is part of same application then you can use `solo.clickOnText("Cancel")`. Same way you can click on other **buttons** by clicking on their **texts**.

Answer (score 1):

Robotium can be difficult when it comes to Android system dialog box buttons however there is a solution.

[Found the answer on this post on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34465170/2355542)

```
// Set this dependency in your app's gradle file
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'
```

and use this code snippet in your test project:

```
// Initialize UiDevice instance
UiDevice uiDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());

// Search for correct button in the dialog.
UiObject button = uiDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().text("ButtonTest"));

if (button.waitForExists(5000)) {
    button.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @kamal_prd said, you cannot because the dialog is not part of the same application.
May be you could use

> clickOnScreen(float x, float y)  //Clicks the specified coordinates

I know it is hard to manage with different screen resolution/size, but it is what I'm also using to test my app.

Answer (score -2):

you can use `solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(buttonId))`

Comment: It is Android OS dialog, not my custom. Are you sure this can help?