# Checking toast message in android espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso, toast

Would anyone know how to test for the appearance of a Toast message in android espresso? In robotium its easy & I used but started working in espresso but dont getting the exact command.

Comment: Any of the following solution won't work if the activity is being finished at the same time as the toast is displayed.

Comment: @Slav did you find any solution that will include Toast checking even in the case when Activity is finished?

Comment: @NixSam Unfortunately not. If I remember correctly, in case of finishing Activity, I settled on checking that the Activity is being finished.

Comment: @Slav thanks for the info

Answer (score 127, accepted):

This slightly long statement works for me:

```
import static android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.RootMatchers.withDecorView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.not;
....
onView(withText(R.string.TOAST_STRING)).inRoot(withDecorView(not(is(getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView())))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Comment: `is()` method is redundant

Comment: @Slava is correct, it can be done by removing is:   onView(withText(R.string.TOAST_STRING)).inRoot(withDecorView(not(getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView())))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()));

Comment: getting cannot resolve method getActivity() Error how to solve this

Comment: @John: You’re probably using the new [JUnit rule-based tests](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/JUnit4RulesInATSL) with an `ActivityTestRule`. You can get the activity from that rule using [`ActivityTestRule#getActivity()`](https://android-test-kit.googlecode.com/git/docs/android-support-test-javadocs-0.2/reference/android/support/test/rule/ActivityTestRule.html#getActivity()).

Comment: With ActivityTestRule: `onView(withText(R.string.toast_text)).inRoot(withDecorView(not(mActivityRule.getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView()))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));`

Comment: This works on a flat layout, but failed on AlertDialog. I had use custom this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33387980/2069407 answer for toast msg on AlertDialog.

Comment: what if I don't know the toast message, consider a case like the toast is a network API error message then how can I detect the toast

Comment: This doesn't work's for dialog's but this does https://stackoverflow.com/a/33387980/7972699

Comment: I am using ActivityScenario.launch(MainActivity::class.java) to launch my activity. How do i get "getActivity()" ?

Comment: @Mervin Hemaraju You could use scenario.onActivity { activity -> ...}

Comment: Is anybody else having trouble with testing toast on Android 11? I just can't make it work. But it works flawlesly on lower version.

Comment: @Brontes Can confirm. Failed with error message: "androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingRootException: Matcher 'with decor view not is".

Comment: @Brontes: Just a note: This approach (and most other answers) does not work on Android 11 API 30, when using `"targetSdkVersion 30"` and `"compileSdkVersion 30"`. See: https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/803

Answer (score 53):

The accepted answer is a good one but didn't work for me. So I searched a bit and found [this blog article](http://baroqueworksdev.blogspot.de/2015/03/how-to-check-toast-window-on-android.html).
This gave me an idea of how to do it and I updated the solution above.

First I implemented the ToastMatcher:

```java
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.test.espresso.Root;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import org.hamcrest.Description;
import org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher;

public class ToastMatcher extends TypeSafeMatcher<Root> {

  @Override
  public void describeTo(Description description) {
    description.appendText("is toast");
  }

  @Override
  public boolean matchesSafely(Root root) {
    int type = root.getWindowLayoutParams().get().type;
    if (type == WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST) {
        IBinder windowToken = root.getDecorView().getWindowToken();
        IBinder appToken = root.getDecorView().getApplicationWindowToken();
        if (windowToken == appToken) {
            // windowToken == appToken means this window isn't contained by any other windows.
            // if it was a window for an activity, it would have TYPE_BASE_APPLICATION.
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
  }

}
```

Then I implemented my check methods like this:

```java
public void isToastMessageDisplayed(int textId) {
    onView(withText(textId)).inRoot(MobileViewMatchers.isToast()).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
```

MobileViewMatchers is a container for accessing the matchers. There I defined the static method `isToast()`.

```
public static Matcher<Root> isToast() {
    return new ToastMatcher();
}
```

This works like a charm for me.

Comment: This isn't working for me, as the test continuously loops. The only thing that works is if I touch the screen while the toast is open it appears to stop idling and will then work. Any ideas?

Comment: I need to know your test setup. What do you want to test and what is displayed? Sounds like a progress issue, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289152/progressbars-and-espresso/36201647#36201647. Does this happen on all API versions?

Comment: I haven't tested multiple API versions. What happens is we are making an API call when a fragment loads, which is mocking a failure response, in which case all we do is show the toast. I can try to make a gist of what I'm doing later on today.

Comment: Where does "MobileViewMatchers" come from? It cant be imported or found in the code

Comment: The method isToast() is defined in that class. With the code above you can use it directly without MobileViewMatchers.

Comment: What do you do if you don't have a textID? The rest of your code retrieves the message correctly, but since I cant match it to the proper view I get an error message

Comment: This works, but testing a Toast is risky as you have to wait for the correct time for it to show up. I was thinking whether it is possible to test a Toast using UiAutomator ?

Comment: WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST is deprecated now.

Comment: I am able to validate toast messages with this code only if toast appears on screen. But if there is a condition with following results : a) msg1 b)msg2 c) No toast at all. Then options a and b are validated but code get stuck in option c. What can be a possible solution for the same ?

Comment: Probably no longer of interest @AdamMc331 but I fixed the endless-loop-issue in my Kotlin version of the code.

Comment: @makovkastar: My Kotlin version addresses the deprecated-issue, too, to be honest by ignoring it. But toasts just seem to be of this deprecated type - at least on API level 27 (in emulator).

Comment: @ThomasR. I've just added an adaption of your code in Kotlin - thanks for the inspiration.

Comment: Please note that `Root` is not part of the public API. The accepted answer above should be the preferred solution.

Comment: This solution had worked well for me until API 30 (Android 11).  Even though I can see a toast on the screen, this code doesn't catch it.  I've moved away from validating toasts altogether; thankfully they're not critical for my application.

Answer (score 15):

If you're using the newest **Android Testing Tools** from **Jetpack**, you know, that `ActivityTestRule` is deprecated and you should use `ActivityScenario` or `ActivityScenarioRule`(which contains the first).

Prerequisites. Create decorView variable and assign it before tests;

```java
@Rule
public ActivityScenarioRule<FeedActivity> activityScenarioRule = new ActivityScenarioRule<>(FeedActivity.class);

private View decorView;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    activityScenarioRule.getScenario().onActivity(new ActivityScenario.ActivityAction<FeedActivity>() {
        @Override
        public void perform(FeedActivityactivity activity) {
            decorView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
        }
    });
}
```

Test itself

```
@Test
public void given_when_thenShouldShowToast() {
    String expectedWarning = getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.error_empty_list);
    onView(withId(R.id.button))
            .perform(click());

    onView(withText(expectedWarning))
            .inRoot(withDecorView(not(decorView)))// Here we use decorView
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
```

*getApplicationContext()* can be taken from `androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext;`

Comment: Thanks a lot! this worked for me, as a suggestion, you can pass the string id to `withText()`

Comment: Also you can get decorView from the rule, as the other answers suggest `.inRoot(withDecorView(not(activityRule.activity.window.decorView)))`

Comment: @Herman there's no way to access a ActivityRule in this example, because we are using a `ActivityScenarioRule`. In this example, your code won't work.

Comment: You should really not(!) store a reference to anything from the activity during the complete test execution. Instead get the reference when you need it. Probably you struggled with the fact, that you cannot set local variables from inside a lambda. Use an AtomicReference to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 14):

First make sure to import:

```
import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.RootMatchers.withDecorView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
```

Inside your class you probably have a rule like this:

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MyNameActivity> activityTestRule =
            new ActivityTestRule<>(MyNameActivity.class);
```

Inside your test:

```
MyNameActivity activity = activityTestRule.getActivity();
onView(withText(R.string.toast_text)).
    inRoot(withDecorView(not(is(activity.getWindow().getDecorView())))).
    check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

This worked for me, and it was pretty easy to use.

Comment: Just a note: This approach (and most other answers) do not work on Android 11 API 30, when using `"targetSdkVersion 30"` and `"compileSdkVersion 30"`. See: https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/803

Answer (score 13):

Though the question has an accepted answer - which BTW does not work for me - I'd like to add my solution in Kotlin which I derived from Thomas R.'s answer:

```
package somepkg

import android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView
import android.support.test.espresso.Root
import android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST
import org.hamcrest.Description
import org.hamcrest.Matcher
import org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher

/**
 * This class allows to match Toast messages in tests with Espresso.
 *
 * Idea taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33387980
 *
 * Usage in test class:
 *
 * import somepkg.ToastMatcher.Companion.onToast
 *
 * // To assert a toast does *not* pop up:
 * onToast("text").check(doesNotExist())
 * onToast(textId).check(doesNotExist())
 *
 * // To assert a toast does pop up:
 * onToast("text").check(matches(isDisplayed()))
 * onToast(textId).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
 */
class ToastMatcher(private val maxFailures: Int = DEFAULT_MAX_FAILURES) : TypeSafeMatcher<Root>() {

    /** Restrict number of false results from matchesSafely to avoid endless loop */
    private var failures = 0

    override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
        description.appendText("is toast")
    }

    public override fun matchesSafely(root: Root): Boolean {
        val type = root.windowLayoutParams.get().type
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION") // TYPE_TOAST is deprecated in favor of TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
        if (type == TYPE_TOAST || type == TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY) {
            val windowToken = root.decorView.windowToken
            val appToken = root.decorView.applicationWindowToken
            if (windowToken === appToken) {
                // windowToken == appToken means this window isn't contained by any other windows.
                // if it was a window for an activity, it would have TYPE_BASE_APPLICATION.
                return true
            }
        }
        // Method is called again if false is returned which is useful because a toast may take some time to pop up. But for
        // obvious reasons an infinite wait isn't of help. So false is only returned as often as maxFailures specifies.
        return (++failures >= maxFailures)
    }

    companion object {

        /** Default for maximum number of retries to wait for the toast to pop up */
        private const val DEFAULT_MAX_FAILURES = 5

        fun onToast(text: String, maxRetries: Int = DEFAULT_MAX_FAILURES) = onView(withText(text)).inRoot(isToast(maxRetries))!!

        fun onToast(textId: Int, maxRetries: Int = DEFAULT_MAX_FAILURES) = onView(withText(textId)).inRoot(isToast(maxRetries))!!

        fun isToast(maxRetries: Int = DEFAULT_MAX_FAILURES): Matcher<Root> {
            return ToastMatcher(maxRetries)
        }
    }

}
```

I hope this will be of help for later readers - the usage is described in the comment.

Comment: This is a really good answer and solved the problem for me because has retry policy integrated

Comment: This works on my older devices but on android 11 it fails on two devices I've tried..

Comment: Thanks. And the package seems changed nowadays, it is `androidx.test.espresso.xxx` now. I mixed this with UIautomator test method together.

Answer (score 12):

First create a cutom Toast Matcher which we can use in our test cases -

```
public class ToastMatcher extends TypeSafeMatcher<Root> {
    
        @Override    public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("is toast");
        }
    
        @Override    public boolean matchesSafely(Root root) {
            int type = root.getWindowLayoutParams().get().type;
            if ((type == WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST)) {
                IBinder windowToken = root.getDecorView().getWindowToken();
                IBinder appToken = root.getDecorView().getApplicationWindowToken();
                if (windowToken == appToken) {
                  //means this window isn't contained by any other windows. 
                  return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
}
```

**1. Test if the Toast Message is Displayed**

```
onView(withText(R.string.mssage)).inRoot(new ToastMatcher())
.check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

**2. Test if the Toast Message is not Displayed**

```
onView(withText(R.string.mssage)).inRoot(new ToastMatcher())
.check(matches(not(isDisplayed())));
```

**3. Test id the Toast contains specific Text Message**

```
onView(withText(R.string.mssage)).inRoot(new ToastMatcher())
.check(matches(withText("Invalid Name"));
```

Thanks,
Anuja

Note - this answer is from [This POST.](http://www.qaautomated.com/2016/01/how-to-test-toast-message-using-espresso.html)

Comment: It should be:
if (windowToken == appToken) {
    //means this window isn't contained by any other windows. 
    return true;
}

Comment: @anuja jain when http://stackoverflow.com/a/40756080/5230044 answer works then why we should refer to your answer

Comment: as noted in the original post in the comments, this does NOT work. It fails with an exception. Also this post is missing the return true; after the comment when the tokens match so it will not work either.

Comment: `Root` is not part of the public API.

Comment: Great answer, this should be the accepted one

Answer (score 5):

I write my custom toast matcher:

```
import android.view.WindowManager
import androidx.test.espresso.Root
import org.hamcrest.Description;
import org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher;
class ToastMatcher : TypeSafeMatcher<Root>() {

    override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
        description.appendText("is toast")
    }

    override fun matchesSafely(root: Root): Boolean {
        val type = root.getWindowLayoutParams().get().type
        if (type == WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST) {
            val windowToken = root.getDecorView().getWindowToken()
            val appToken = root.getDecorView().getApplicationWindowToken()
            if (windowToken === appToken) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

And use like this:

```
onView(withText(R.string.please_input_all_fields)).inRoot(ToastMatcher()).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
```

Answer (score 5):

For kotlin, I had to use the apply extension function, and this worked for me.

1- declare your ToastMatcher class in the androidTest folder:

```
class ToastMatcher : TypeSafeMatcher<Root?>() {

override fun matchesSafely(item: Root?): Boolean {
        val type: Int? = item?.windowLayoutParams?.get()?.type
        if (type == WindowManager.LayoutParams.FIRST_APPLICATION_WINDOW) {
            val windowToken: IBinder = item.decorView.windowToken
            val appToken: IBinder = item.decorView.applicationWindowToken
            if (windowToken === appToken) { // means this window isn't contained by any other windows.
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    override fun describeTo(description: Description?) {
        description?.appendText("is toast")
    }
}
```

2- Then you use like this to test that the toast message actually displays

```
onView(withText(R.string.invalid_phone_number))
        .inRoot(ToastMatcher().apply {
            matches(isDisplayed())
        });
```

Attribution to ToastMatcher class:

```
/**
 * Author: http://www.qaautomated.com/2016/01/how-to-test-toast-message-using-espresso.html
 */
```

Comment: it's false positive pass, you can match any String

Answer (score 2):

I would say for toast messages first define your rule

```
 @Rule
   public ActivityTestRule<AuthActivity> activityTestRule =
   new ActivityTestRule<>(AuthActivity.class);
```

then whatever toast message text you are looking for type it in between quotation 
       for example I used "Invalid email address"

```
   onView(withText("Invalid email address"))
    .inRoot(withDecorView(not(activityTestRule.getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView())))
    .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest an alternative method, especially if you need to check that particular toast is **NOT** displayed

The problem here that

```
onView(viewMatcher)
    .inRoot(RootMatchers.isPlatformPopup())
    .check(matches(not(isDisplayed())))
```

or

```
onView(viewMatcher)
    .inRoot(RootMatchers.isPlatformPopup())
    .check(doesNotExist())
```

or any other custom `inRoot` checks
are throwing `NoMatchingRootException` even before the code passes to `check` method

You may just catch the exception and complete the test but that's not a good option since throwing and catching `NoMatchingRootException` consumes a lot of time in a comparison with the default test case. Seems that Espresso is waiting for the Root for a while

For this case is suggest just to give up with espresso here and use `UiAutomator` for this assertion. The `Espresso` and `UiAutomator` frameworks could easily work together in one environment.

```
val device: UiDevice
   get() = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())

fun assertPopupIsNotDisplayed() {
    device.waitForIdle()
    assertFalse(device.hasObject(By.text(yourText))))
}

fun assertPopupIsDisplayed() {
    device.waitForIdle()
    assertTrue(device.hasObject(By.text(yourText))))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using ActivityScenarioRule and Java

Some imports for the code

```java
import android.view.View;
import androidx.test.ext.junit.rules.ActivityScenarioRule;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;

import static androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.RootMatchers.withDecorView;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.not;
```

**1. Declare the rule**

```java
//Change YourActivity by the activity you are testing
@Rule
public ActivityScenarioRule<YourActivity> activityRule
        = new ActivityScenarioRule<>(YourActivity.class);
```

**2. Initialize the decor view**

```java
    private View decorView;

    @Before
    public void loadDecorView() {
        activityRule.getScenario().onActivity(
                activity -> decorView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView()
        );
    }
```

**3. Finally test it**

```java
    @Test
    public void testWithToasts() {


        //Arrange and act code

        //Modify toast_msg to your own string resource
        onView(withText(R.string.toast_msg)).
                inRoot(RootMatchers.withDecorView(not(decorView)))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to this, but I made a base class 'BaseTest' that has all of my actions (swiping, clicking, etc.) and verifications (checking text views for content, etc.).

```
protected fun verifyToastMessageWithText(text: String, activityTestRule: ActivityTestRule<*>) {
        onView(withText(text)).inRoot(withDecorView(not(activityTestRule.activity.window.decorView))).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }

protected fun verifyToastMessageWithStringResource(id: Int, activityTestRule: ActivityTestRule<*>) {
        onView(withText(id)).inRoot(withDecorView(not(activityTestRule.activity.window.decorView))).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> this works for me

onView(withId(R.id.inputField)).check(matches(withText("Lalala")));

Answer (score -3):

The way Toasts are implemented makes it possible to detect a toast has been displayed. However there is no way to see if a Toast has been requested, thru a call to show()) or to block between the period of time between show() and when the toast has become visible. This is opens up unresolvable timing issues (that you can only address thru sleep & hope).

If you really really want to verify this, here's a not-so-pretty alternative using Mockito and a test spy:

```
public interface Toaster {
 public void showToast(Toast t);

 private static class RealToaster {
  @Override
  public void showToast(Toast t) {
    t.show();
  }

 public static Toaster makeToaster() {
   return new RealToaster();
 }
}

Then in your test

public void testMyThing() {
 Toaster spyToaster = Mockito.spy(Toaster.makeToaster());
 getActivity().setToaster(spyToaster);
 onView(withId(R.button)).perform(click());
 getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
 @Override
  public void run() {
   // must do this on the main thread because the matcher will be interrogating a view...
   Mockito.verify(spyToaster).showToast(allOf(withDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT), withView(withText("hello world"));
 });
}

// create a matcher that calls getDuration() on the toast object
Matcher<Toast> withDuration(int)
// create a matcher that calls getView() and applies the given view matcher
Matcher<Toast> withView(Matcher<View> viewMatcher)




another answer regarding this 




if(someToast == null)
    someToast = Toast.makeText(this, "sdfdsf", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
boolean isShown = someToast.getView().isShown();
```

Comment: Md Hussain, don't you want to add a link in your answer to the place where you copied it - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/android-test-kit-discuss/toast/android-test-kit-discuss/uaHdXuVm-Bw/EBIGyA0Omj0J ?

Comment: Although it's true that the answer is copied, it raises a good point. The accepted answer provides a non-hermetical test, since it affects a potential  following execution.