# Espresso testing for toast on button click

Tags: android, ui-testing, android-espresso

I am trying to test for toast that is being generated when i click on button using espresso. Can anyone suggest me how to do it with proper explanation with code?

Comment: your question is extremely broad.  Do you have a specific problem that SO users can help you with?  If you simply need to learn how to use espresso for UI testing, go read any of the many tutorials that you can find on the other end of a google search.

Comment: The question has been answered at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33387980/1270534

Comment: that worked .....thx @piotrek1543