# Record Espresso Testcases in Android studio 2.2

Tags: android, assert, android-espresso, android-studio-2.2, android-espresso-recorder

I am using Android studio 2.2 and try to record Espresso test. I am unable to add asserts to Toast messages, EditText error message or Snackbar message.
I am getting below exception for Snackbar text

```
 android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: (with id: com.example.root.myapplication:id/snackbar_text and with text: is "enter email" and Child at position 0 in parent Child at position 2 in parent an instance of android.view.ViewGroup and is displayed on the screen to the user)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

View Hierarchy:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking toast message in android espresso](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390574/checking-toast-message-in-android-espresso)

Comment: @HowieH Thanks but I am taking about recording of espresso test in Android Studio 2.2 . I don't want to write code as now we can simply record the steps and add assertion on UI component using Studio 2.2