# Testing Toast Message using Espresso is not Resolved

Tags: android, android-espresso, toast

I am not able to test the Toast Message using the Espresso.There are many question as well as answer associated to it but i am not able to Solve the issue.

**TestingCode**

```
 class ToastMatcher extends TypeSafeMatcher<Root> {

    @Override
    public boolean matchesSafely(Root root) {
        int type = root.getWindowLayoutParams().get().type;
        if ((type == WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST)) {
            IBinder windowToken = root.getDecorView().getWindowToken();
            IBinder appToken = root.getDecorView().getApplicationWindowToken();
            if (windowToken == appToken) {
                return true;
                //means this window isn't contained by any other windows.
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

     @Override
     public void describeTo(Description description) {

         description.appendText(String.valueOf(R.string.messsage_login_successful));
     }
 }


   @Test
    public void btnLoginClickWithPassingUserNameAndPassword() throws Exception {
        onView(withId(R.id.etUsername)).perform(clearText());
        onView(withId(R.id.etUsername)).perform(typeText(userName));
        onView(withId(R.id.etPassword)).perform(typeText(passWord));
        onView(withId(R.id.btnLogin)).perform(click());

//        onView(withText(R.string.messsage_login_successful)).inRoot(withDecorView(not(mActivityRule.getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView()))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
     //   onView(withText(R.string.messsage_login_successful)).inRoot(withDecorView(not(is(mActivityRule.getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView())))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));

        onView(withText(R.string.messsage_login_successful)).inRoot(new ToastMatcher())
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()));

    }
```

**Issue i got**

```
android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with string from resource id: <2131689608>[messsage_login_successful] value: Logged In Successfully
If the target view is not part of the view hierarchy, you may need to use Espresso.onData to load it from one of the following AdapterViews:android.widget.GridView{52a6eb90 VFED.VC. .F...... 60,112-884,904 #7f0a007c app:id/dashMenu}

View Hierarchy:
+>DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1920, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) ty=1 fl=#1810100 pfl=0x8 wanim=0x10302a1}, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
```

> How can this issue be solved.I am always getting  No views in
>   hierarchy found matching ?

Answer (score 2):

This Statement works for me.

```
import static android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.RootMatchers.withDecorView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.not;

onView(withText(R.string.TOAST_STRING)).inRoot(withDecorView(not(getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView()))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

or use Custom Matcher to achieve this

```
public class ToastMatcher extends TypeSafeMatcher<Root> {

    @Override    public boolean matchesSafely(Root root) {
        int type = root.getWindowLayoutParams().get().type;
        if ((type == WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST)) {
            IBinder windowToken = root.getDecorView().getWindowToken();
            IBinder appToken = root.getDecorView().getApplicationWindowToken();
            if (windowToken == appToken) {
              return true;
            //means this window isn't contained by any other windows.
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Test if the Toast Message is Displayed

```
onView(withText(R.string.mssage)).inRoot(new ToastMatcher())
.check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Test if the Toast Message is not Displayed

```
onView(withText(R.string.mssage)).inRoot(new ToastMatcher())
.check(matches(not(isDisplayed())));
```

Test id the Toast contains specific Text Message

```
onView(withText(R.string.mssage)).inRoot(new ToastMatcher())
.check(matches(withText("Invalid Name"));
```

Comment: I have tried this .But not Able to solve my issue
@BhavikMakwana The Toast is not associated with Another class

Comment: You have is() method is redundant at not(is(mActivityRule.getActivity()...)

Comment: same issue
  onView(withText(R.string.messsage_login_successful)).inRoot(withDecorView(not(mActivityRule.getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView()))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));

Comment: try to implement custom matcher.

Comment: sure .What we have to set in here. if we used CustomMatcher
  description.appendText("is toast");

I always get this issue  No views in hierarchy found matching: with string from resource id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158157/discussion-between-ghimire-and-bhavik-makwana).

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same issue, using **Android 11**. With every other Android Version your code just works fine (for me).
Unfortunately I could not yet find any solution. Not even UIAutomator seems to detect toasts on Android 11 (as suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61404621/5369727)).