# Android Test if toast is shown

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-espresso, android-toast

I am writing a test to check if a custom `Toast` is being shown.
The Toast is not being constructed and shown in an `Activity` instance. I have a created a class that has access to the `Context`.

```
public class ToastHandler{
    private Context context;
    public ToastHander(Context context){
       this.context = context;
    }

   public createToast(DataStructure data){
      // Create and show Custom Toast using data and context
   }
}
```

How should I go about testing this? I am using Espresso.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking toast message in android espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390574/checking-toast-message-in-android-espresso)

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
onView(withText(R.string.toast_text)).inRoot(withDecorView(not(mActivityRule.getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView()))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

?

If there is such need you can create matcher like this

http://baroqueworksdev.blogspot.de/2015/03/how-to-check-toast-window-on-android.html

Comment: How to get `mActivityRule`. I don't need to start an Activity I want to test the `Toast`being shown only.

Comment: Espresso is for view (UI) testing, if you are trying to test toast without views maybe its not the case for you to use espresso, ok? AFAIK you need at least app context to show toast, am i wrong?:)

Comment: i mean you going to test system behavior, not your app and thats the case - your code can be tested by jUnit only

Comment: I am using espresso so I can access the application's Context. I can't test that with jUnit only.

Comment: i dont know what are you really going to test? if that method invoked shows toast? is that background/service case?

Comment: It is going to be shown from activities and background services.