# Unable to get toast message in UI Automator

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-espresso, android-uiautomator

in our app we are using  `Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.contact_not_present), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`  to show toast message

For Ui Automation we are using
https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator

While automating a use case which should fire a Toast message ,As expected the toast message was fired but i am unable to find it

I am trying to locate the element by

```
UiObject2 object = device.wait(Until.findObject(By.clazz("android.widget.Toast")), 9000);
```

But i am always getting the object as null

can anyone help me on this ?

Comment: It may be better to [use Espresso to check for Toast messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390574/checking-toast-message-in-android-espresso), rather than use UI Automator. But note that checking for Toasts does not work with `targetSdkVersion 30` and `Android 11 (API 30)`. See: https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/803