# Using Android Espresso to check Toast Messages

Tags: android, automation, android-espresso, software-quality

I'm having trouble checking if a Toast is present on the screen using Android Espresso.

Are there any other ways to do this?
In my specific case, the Toast is triggered on the login screen, but it's only on the next screen that I attempt to test for the presence of the Toast, which may or may not be there.

I've tried all the solutions I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390574/checking-toast-message-in-android-espresso).